# VB.Net - Get name of computer that is running a local file

Tags: vb.net, networking

Is it possible to retrieve the name (or IP address, whichever) of a computer that is accessing a file on my shared folders via workgroup? If so, what would I need to retrieve it? Filename? File directory?

I am using vb.net 2005.

Comment: What type of file is it an how is it accessed?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

But, if you are on the computer that has the share, you can go into Administrative Tools>>Computer Management>>System Tools>>Shared Folders>>Open Files and and you might get some information about what files and who.  But this is not reliable because only certain files apply locking and they will only show up here if locked from another computer.  Too often windows will tell you the file is locked but you will not see the information in here.